# Requirements for disabled line for domestic flights in India

Tags: india, domestic-travel, accessibility

I am an Indian citizen and I am in a cast, do I get to go in a disabled line for Indian domestic flights?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. Just to clarify disabled line where - checkin, boarding or security? Would you require wheel chair assistance?

Comment: If you can manage but slowly contact your airline and ask if you qualify for assistance in the airports. Often airlines and airports are rather helpful but I do not have experience with India and its rules.